# Why some filters shown at "Security filter chain" by debug are not listed in the complete list of the "addFilter" method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

For a `Spring Boot` **3.1.1** project working with:

- *Spring Web*
- *Thymeleaf*
- *Spring Data JPA*
- *MySQL Driver*
- *H2 Database*
- *Spring Security*

In the project, about `Spring Security` when is applied

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
class SecurityConfig {

 ... 

}
```

When the app starts appears:

```
Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
  DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]
```

Now, about to create a custom `Filter` to be included in that chain, the `HttpSecurity` class is used together with the `addFilter` method as follows:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
        HttpSecurity http, @Qualifier("customFilter") Filter filter) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterAfter(filter, SwitchUserFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}
```

The point is, if you open the `addFilter` method of the `HttpSecurity` class, appears:

```java
@Override
public HttpSecurity addFilter(Filter filter) {
   ...
}
```

**Note**

Using the same IDE and navigating through the classes/interfaces available according the jars downloaded from `Spring Boot` + `Spring Security` according by their own dependencies **then** ...

Because the `addFilter` method has `@Override`, the *super implementation* is declared at the `HttpSecurityBuilder` interface and the `addFilter` method is declared as follows:

```java
/**
 * Adds a {@link Filter} that must be an instance of or extend one of the Filters
 * provided within the Security framework. The method ensures that the ordering of the
 * Filters is automatically taken care of.
 *
 * The ordering of the Filters is:
 *
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link ForceEagerSessionCreationFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link DisableEncodeUrlFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link ChannelProcessingFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link SecurityContextPersistenceFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link LogoutFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link X509AuthenticationFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter}</li>
 * <li><a href="
 * {@docRoot}/org/springframework/security/cas/web/CasAuthenticationFilter.html">CasAuthenticationFilter</a></li>
 * <li>{@link UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link ConcurrentSessionFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link DigestAuthenticationFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link BasicAuthenticationFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link RequestCacheAwareFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link JaasApiIntegrationFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link RememberMeAuthenticationFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link AnonymousAuthenticationFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link SessionManagementFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link ExceptionTranslationFilter}</li>
 * <li>{@link FilterSecurityInterceptor}</li>
 * <li>{@link SwitchUserFilter}</li>
 * </ul>
 * @param filter the {@link Filter} to add
 * @return the {@link HttpSecurity} for further customizations
 */
H addFilter(Filter filter);
```

As you can see the lists are not the same. The latter list has more Filters because it is considering more dependencies involved in security, such as X509, CAS, JAAS. ***Is it the complete list, right?***. Furthermore it indicates: `The ordering of the Filters is:`

The point is, if the former list (the smaller) is a subset of the latter, why some Filters shown in there do not appear in the latter?

For example `CsrfFilter` and `AuthorizationFilter` and more ...

**Question**

- Why some filters shown at *"Security filter chain"* by debug are not listed in the complete list of the `addFilter` method?

***Even more***

As third list, at the official Reference Documentation, at the [Adding in Your Own Filters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/xml-namespace.html#ns-custom-filters) section, has a similar list.

I thought it is a sub-list of the longest (referred now as second) because they are listed through *Table 1. Standard Filter Aliases and Ordering*, but exists some filters of this third list that are not listed in the second list: for example `CsrfFilter` and `HeaderWriterFilter` ... and even more, the order of the filters are not the same between the third and second lists, do a simple comparison of the first and second filters for each list. They are inverted

Second List (current API)

- `ForceEagerSessionCreationFilter`
- `DisableEncodeUrlFilter`
- ...

Third List (Reference Documentation)

- `DisableEncodeUrlFilter`
- `ForceEagerSessionCreationFilter`
- ...

The same happens for other Filters too

Comment: so you are basically asking why the docs are not up to date, this is more suited as an issue presented to spring security than asking on stack overflow, and im guessing they are more than welcome to accept pull requests to align the docs.

Comment: So you are asking why the docs aren't up to date or why not every possible filter from every security provider (Keycloak and others) isn't in the list of the common Spring Security documentation. But Spring Security is open-source so feel free to create a pull request to align all three and try to add all available and possible combinations of filters.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I thought from the beginning in create an issue in GitHub, but because I assumed this situation could have a logical explanation ... I created this post ...

Comment: For the audience - reported at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13604